# Subsonic it's not generate the class templates for MySQL in LINQ 4Temapltes

Tags: subsonic3

Iam try to configure and generate the files for subsonic 3.0.0.3 using MySQL. I using the 4 templates to LINQ, but the class.cs it's not generate. Someone can help-me? All the configs works.

Answer (score 0):

The class files don't generate the same way they did in SubSonic 2. In SubSonic 2, you had a class.cs file for each object (table, view, etc.).

In SubSonic 3, you have 1 .cs file that has all of the table classes inside of it. For example, if you're using ActiveRecord, then you would have a ActiveRecord.tt file and under that (use expand/collapse) there's a ActiveRecord.cs file. Inside of that ActiveRecord.cs file will be all of your classes.

I don't know the name of your templates, but if you look inside/within the .tt to find the .cs, then the classes should be inside of that .cs file.